# Is there a way besides integration by parts to solve this integral?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, vector-analysis

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} -10\cos^9(t)\sin^4(t)t^4\,dt$$

Maybe a formula for this form or something?

Comment: Because $e^{it} = \cos t + i \sin t$, your question is equivalent to asking if $\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{it} t^n dt$ can be computed without integration by parts. Contour integral perhaps? That's my only guess.